# Given an array of integers, reverse every maximal strictly ascending subarray

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops

How would I rearrange the elements of a given array of integers in place so that the elements of every maximal strictly ascending subarray are reversed?

For example, given the array { 5, 7, 10, 4, 2, 7, 8, 1, 3 }, after executing this method, the elements of the array would be { 10, 7, 5, 4, 8, 7, 2, 3, 1 }.

My attempt only sorts the integers in descending order. How can I make these nested loops identify the maximal strictly ascending subarrays? I believe the outer loop should have to repeatedly find the end of the current ascending sequence, while the inner loop reverses the subarray up to that point.

```
public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    int[] arr = {5, 7, 10, 4, 2, 7, 8, 1, 3};

    for (int i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++) {

        if (arr[i] < arr[i+1]) {
            int t = arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = t;
        }
        for (int j=0; j<arr.length-1; j++) {

            if (arr[j] < arr[j+1]) {
                int t = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = t;
            }
        }
    }
    String result = Arrays.toString(arr);
    System.out.println(result); // [10, 8, 7, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you nest-looping like this?

Comment: HINT: don't swap anything until you've **found the end of a sub-sequence**

Comment: bubble sort will work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see why you are using nested loop. But I think you'll need to keep track of start and end instead of just swapping. Here's how I solved it using a stack:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reverseAscendingSubArray(new int[]{5, 7, 10, 4, 2, 7, 8, 1, 3})));
}

private static int[] reverseAscendingSubArray(int[] arr) {
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    int[] result = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || arr[i - 1] < arr[i]) {
            stack.push(arr[i]);
        } else {
            for (int j = stack.size(); j > 0; j--) {
                result[i - j] = stack.pop();
            }
            stack.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    if (!stack.empty()) {
        for (int j = stack.size(); j > 0; j--) {
            result[arr.length - j] = stack.pop();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Output**

```
[10, 7, 5, 4, 8, 7, 2, 3, 1]
```

**Explanation**

I keep pushing elements into the stack until the current element is greater than the previous one. As soon as I get something smaller than the previous, I pop all elements from the stack and write them to a new array. This pushing and popping will reverse the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using bubble sort as in the code below.

```
public static void reverseAscendingSubarrays(int[] items){
        int start = -1;
        int stop = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
            if (i != items.length - 1){
                if (items[i] <= items[i + 1]){
                    if (start == -1) {
                        start = i;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (start != -1) {
                        stop = i;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                if (start != -1){
                    stop = i;
                }
            }
            if (start != -1 && stop != -1){
                //sort array from start to stop (uses bubble sort - inefficient for large arrays)
                for (int n = 0; n < stop - start + 1; n++)
                    for (int j = start; j < stop; j++){
                        if (items[j] < items[j+1]){
                            //swap
                            int temp = items[j];
                            items[j] =items[j+1];
                            items[j+1] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                start = -1;
                stop = -1;
            }
        }
    }
```